# How can I find the $n^{th}$ 'reversible prime'?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I just thought of an interesting problem when discussing prime numbers with a friend.

Some numbers are prime, but even fewer numbers preserve their primality when we reverse their digits.

So for example:

> $13$ is prime and $31$ is also prime.

I'll call these 'reversible primes' informally.

I was wondering, is there a way of determining the $n^{th}$ 'reversible prime' or an efficient sieve for them?

Comment: Is there a known relation between the base of a number and the event "is prime"? If so: This may be the key. If not: Then I don't think you will get an answer to this - in exact terms. Algorithmic methods may exist.

Comment: A good observation to start with is that the first and last digit can only be 1, 3, 7, 9 (because divisibility by respectively 2 and 5)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking for. Could you provide some example answer in a simpler case, e.g. in case of twin primes or something else?

Comment: I am happy with an algorithmic method, if one exists. That is something I would be happy to investigate as a little project.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called an Emirp: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirp

Comment: @Wojowu so for example, the first reversible prime is 13. The second is 17 and so on. If someone asked you "Find the 2016th reversible prime", what steps could you take to find it other than brute force computer checks crawling up the integers one by one?

Comment: Looking up the references from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Emirp.html and of the wikipedia link, together with http://oeis.org/A006567 - I think there is no known algorithm better than brute-force.

Comment: Study binary emirps (3, 5, 7 are trivially reversible, 11, 13, 23, 29 are a little more interesting). Either you will get an insight or grow bored of the topic.

Comment: If your notion of reversible primes includes the palindomes $11, 101, 131,\ldots$, the appropriate OEIS entry is http://oeis.org/A007500

Comment: @RobertSoupe 32 and 29 are obviously not emirps.  Um, am I missing something in the question though?  A sieve for primes by eliminating multiples can be trivially modified to rule out the reversals of multiples, so that's an obvious method to find the nth emirp.  As for any other method... is there any other method than a sieve to find the n-th normal prime?

Comment: Example: Sieve to find the emrips less than 10.  2.  remove multiples of 2 (too many to list but) every number with and even digit is ruled out.  3. remove 9,15,51,33,39,93,57,75.  5. remove 35,53,57,75,59,95, 7 remove 77, 91, 19.  Now you've reach sqrt 100 so what's left are the emirps:2,3,5,7,11,13,31,17,71,37, 73.  So sieve seems to work to me?

Comment: @fleablood You're right, they're not emirps in base 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what i have observed from

> The concept you're looking for is called an Emirp: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirp – Jasper 4 mins ago

comment is as follows:

NOTE: this is purely on the basis of the observation of the number given in the [given list](http://oeis.org/A006567/list)

let there be such a number which is 'reversible prime'. Let $j$ be the sum of all the digits in that number

from observation $j$ is divisible by 2 or 3 or 5 or is itself a prime. well that could be a test but this could not be the only test. let it be called the test A. actually $j$ was coming again and again 4,5,8,10,13,14,16,17,19 and let it be called list A and other interesting thing to be noted is that there is not any single number in list A which is divisible by 2 and 3 simultaneously i.e. it is not divisible by 6

now from observation again we can see that these numbers are ended and started with 1,3,7,9 and one thing can also be noted that any of the number at the first place is not repeated at the last hence many possibility has been removed(this observation can also be understood as we are checking the 'reversible primes'). let is be called 'B'

now for numbers that are coming in middle of the first number and the last number, they are 0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 but not 2.

---

**If we use Test A and 'B' then we can by trial and error method guess the weather the number $n$ is a 'reversible prime' or not by remembering that the sum of the digit of that number should be one of the number given in the list A and that number should contain 1 or 3 or 7 or 9 at the first place but at the last place it, same digit(which is selected for the first place) should not be repeated.**

For example you select a number(which should be a prime), suppose, 149 
then the sum of the digit is 14 which is in list A and is divisible by 2 but not by 2 and 3 simultaneously and the number between the first digit and last digit is not 2 and the first digit and last digit is from 1, 3, 7, 9 and are not equal hence there are many-many chances that this number is 'reversible prime'